# Ban two commas in a row in the text field javafx

Tags: regex, javafx, textfield

I need to enter a sequence of numbers separated by commas to the text field. I forbid to enter all characters except commas and digits. But entering two commas in the line remains possible. Regexp like \d+\,? in this case don't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class TextFieldCustom extends TextField {

  public TextFieldCustom(){
  }

  @Override
  public void replaceText(int start, int end, String string) {
    if (string.matches("[0-9,]")|| string.isEmpty()){
        super.replaceText(start, end, string);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void replaceSelection(String string){
    super.replaceSelection(string);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Below is an example.
Also instead of `replace` it's easier to use ChangeListener.

```
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (!newValue.matches("(?!.*,,)[\\d,]*")) {
                ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Explanation**

```
(?!     # it means that everything after should not be matched
.*,,    # any symbols followed by double comma
)       # close lookahead
[\\d,]* # matched digits and commas in any amounts
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I need! To avoid alternated commas and dots in real numbers it turned out: "(?!.*,,|.*\\.\\.|.*\\.,|.*,\\.)[\\d,.]*") And it's works for me!

Comment: @Роман a bit of overkill, try slightly shorter version: `"(?!.*[\\.,]{2,})[\\d,\\.]*"`

Comment: Thank you @Sergey! Your help makes me strong! I found one more possible mistake: if use the solution proposed by you, I can type this: 2,2.1.2
That is, after entering a point and a number, it is possible to enter once again a point, and there must be only a number or comma. I do not understand how to solve this.

Comment: @Роман it looks like a totally separate restriction, please ask it in another question to avoid making a mess out of this one.

Comment: I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746807/regexp-for-prohibit-entering-a-point-after-entering-a-point-and-number-javafx

Answer (score 0):

A regex that matches a string that matches a string that only contains one or more digits, followed with any number of `,` + digit(s) sequences, you may use

```
s.matches("[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RnU1Kf/1).

The `String#matches()` method anchors the string by default, so you do not need the `\A` (or `^`, start of string) and `\z` (=the very end of string) anchors.

- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:,[0-9]+)*` - zero or more  (`*`) sequences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits.