# Regexp for prohibit entering a point after entering a point and number JavaFX

Tags: java, regex, javafx

I need input consecutive integers and real numbers separated by commas, like this: 2,12.4,3
I forbid entering sequentially two commas, two points, and all other characters, except numbers, by the following expression: `(?!.*[\\.,]{2,})[\\d,\\.]*`
But with it I can type this: 2,12.4.3 
That is, after entering a point and a number, it is possible to enter once again a point, and there must be only a number or comma.
I need to leave all the conditions from the previous expression, and deny entering the point, if before this point, through the numbers (\d+), there is a point.

```
@FXML
private TextField tf;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    tf.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
        if (!newValue.matches("(?!.*[\\.,]{2,})[\\d,\\.]*")) {
            ((StringProperty) observable).setValue(oldValue);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Is this for homework (i.e. has to be exactly like this) or are you just trying to parse a bunch of numbers from user input?

Comment: Does knowing it matter? @pvg

Comment: @revo yes. There are much saner ways to do this than with a regex. For starters, comma is a terrible separator. But if it's for an assignment that specifies precisely this, there's not much point talking about doing it some other way

Comment: As long as the question is tagged with `regex`, it doesn't matter to be a homework or a real problem. However you may bid your solution according to other tags as well. Nothing's wrong with it. @pvg

Comment: @revo I didn't say there was anything wrong with it. But if the problem is 'parse a bunch of numbers from user input' there are better ways to do that.  What exactly is your issue here?

Comment: I said *nothing's wrong* with *adding your own different solution* under this topic. That's all. @pvg

Comment: @pvg, yes, it's assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more specific in finding a solution:

```
^(?:\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?,)*\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY0IaI/1)

Comment: I'am moderate input by means of listener. And you decision don't work for me.

Comment: Remove your comment and for the sake of readability add it to your question. Formatting also can be done there. @RomanKuznetsov

Comment: Remove leading and trailing anchors (`^` & `$`) and check if works. @RomanKuznetsov

Comment: It's was first what I did. @revo